# Xamarin datagrid cell click event

Tags: xamarin, datagrid, click, cell

Recently, I need to do a project using Xamarin Gridview. As I am very new to this, I have difficulty to add a cell click event to a dg:datagrid component. Do anyone know how to do this? Thank you for any useful experience shared with me.

BR,
Terry

Comment: Xamarin doesn’t have a native DataGrid.  If you are using a 3rd party control, please tell us which specific one you are using

Comment: If you are using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/) then try `ItemSelected`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `SelectedItem` to the DataGrid. You can check this document about the [Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid#-usage-see-all) for more infromation.

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam}"
               RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8"
               PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
```